# Random generation of complex entities with relations between properties

Tags: javascript, procedural-generation

Idea:

I want to build an app that generates creatures based on JSON like plan
A creature is a bunch of properties and values. User can pick some of values manually, others are generated
There are correlations between properties, that work both ways - if user sets creature mass to be very heavy then it's environment more likely would be aquatic or low gravity and vice versa - if it's aquatic, it'l have more chances to be heavy.

Plan should be separated from functionality that would use it. After functionality is done, plan could be replaced with something else like a city generator instead of a creature, or creature described by different properties.

Also it is a bit complex - there may be different types of parameters - numerical, pick from different sets of variants, multiple pick. As well as relations between them: *x +x alter set of variants etc

I could develop this all from scratch, but that would require some effort because currently I do not have a clear idea how to do that. So I wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel if there is one

Question:

So is there some js library for this?
Are there such libraries in other languages or perhaps entire languages better suited for problems such as this than js?
Like R? does it have some tools for that?

Also. If there is some information on this topic (books, articles, perhaps some math concepts,  it also would be useful. Feel free to share anything, because I'm starting from a blank page

Thanks

Clarification:

It's not about graphics or a way to displaying it. 
The input is jsonlike structure with property names, possible values and relations + some user choices 
The output is another jsonlike structure with properties and chosen values

properties might be something like 
size:"30kg", trophicType:"carnivore", activity:{"day-night":nocturnal} etc

Comment: _"I could develop this all from scratch"_ Have you tried? _"but that would require some effort because currently I do not have a clear idea how to do that."_ Yes, effort would be required.

Comment: You really have no idea, right? Anyway... I would go for welGL (probably Three.js) for that... but its a unrealistic task/goal.

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, and I've understood that it'll take quite a lot of time.

Comment: "If there is some information on this topic (books, articles)" is clearly off topic here, so is asking for libraries. I really suggest you dig in google... You might like what you could find on https://www.reddit.com/r/proceduralgeneration/